# OpenLayers3 examples offline

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to get the following example to work on my own webserver:

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/static-image.html

It works fine from the link, but if I checkout the OpenLayers3 git repository:

```
cd www
git clone https://github.com/openlayers/ol3.git
```

But if I then go to the examples in Firefox (Debian) I only see a gray back where the map should be. What do I need to do to get the examples working? I tried removing loader.js and referencing static-image.js directly. But that didn't work. I'm slightly at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using directly Git repository with `git clone https://github.com/openlayers/ol3.git` is for advanced users or core developers (See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

You should better make things simple for getting started.

- Go to https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases
- Click on the green button named "v3.0.0.zip"
- unzip the downloaded file in a webserver
- open the browser with an url similar to `http://serverurl/path/to/examples/static-image.html`

And it works.

PS: If you are really offline, download image from `http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png` and change this same url in static-image.js file to the local downloaded file.